# How to use the following model class (Framework 4.7) in a Framework 2.0?

Tags: vb.net

I have the following model class used in my .NET Framework 4.7.2 project which get and set data from an API.

I have to use the same model class in a .NET 2.0 Project which will have to get and set the same object get from a HTTP request (not API)

But if i try just to copy paste it i get the error which says that i need a setter on it.

Here is how my model looks like:

```
Public Class PDT


    Public Class Documento
        Public Property testata As Testata
        Public Property corpo() As IEnumerable(Of Corpo)
    End Class


    Public Class Testata
        Public Property id As Integer
        Public Property cod As String
        Public Property tipo As String
        Public Property cod_fornitore As String
        Public Property desc_fornitore As String
        Public Property data As String
        Public Property num_pv As String
        Public Property desc_pv As String
        Public Property num_pv_destinazione As String
        Public Property desc_pv_destinazione As String
        Public Property num_ordine As String
        Public Property inviato As Boolean
    End Class

    Public Class Corpo
        Public Property barcode As String
        Public Property desc As String
        Public Property um As String
        Public Property qta As Single
        Public Property id_testata As Integer
        Public Property tipo_frontalino As String
        Public Property timestamp As Long
    End Class



End Class
```

PS I've tried setting getter and setters like this for each property:

```
    Public Property testata() As Testata
        Get
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Testata)
        End Set
    End Property
```

But by passing data in that object returns always `Nothing`.

UPDATE my class with getters and setters:

```
Public Class PDT
    Public Class Documento

        Private _testata As Testata = Nothing

        Public Property testata As Testata
            Get
                Return _testata
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Testata)
                _testata = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _corpo As IEnumerable(Of Corpo) = Nothing
        Public Property corpo As IEnumerable(Of Corpo)
            Get
                Return _corpo
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As IEnumerable(Of Corpo))
                _corpo = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
    Public Class Testata

        Private _id As Integer = Nothing
        Public Property id As Integer
            Get
                Return _id
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _id = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _cod As String = Nothing
        Public Property cod As String
            Get
                Return _cod
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _cod = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _tipo As String = Nothing
        Public Property tipo As String
            Get
                Return _tipo
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _tipo = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _cod_fornitore As String = Nothing
        Public Property cod_fornitore As String
            Get
                Return _cod_fornitore
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _cod_fornitore = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _desc_fornitore As String = Nothing
        Public Property desc_fornitore As String
            Get
                Return _desc_fornitore
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _desc_fornitore = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _data As String = Nothing
        Public Property data As String
            Get
                Return _data
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _data = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _num_pv As String = Nothing
        Public Property num_pv As String
            Get
                Return _num_pv
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _num_pv = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _desc_pv As String = Nothing
        Public Property desc_pv As String
            Get
                Return _desc_pv
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _desc_pv = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _num_pv_destinazione As String = Nothing
        Public Property num_pv_destinazione As String
            Get
                Return _num_pv_destinazione
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _num_pv_destinazione = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _desc_pv_destinazione As String = Nothing
        Public Property desc_pv_destinazione As String
            Get
                Return _desc_pv_destinazione
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _desc_pv_destinazione = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _num_ordine As String = Nothing
        Public Property num_ordine As String
            Get
                Return _num_ordine
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _num_ordine = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _inviato As Boolean = Nothing

        Public Property inviato As Boolean
            Get
                Return _inviato
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
                _inviato = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
    Public Class Corpo

        Private _barcode As String = Nothing
        Public Property barcode As String
            Get
                Return _barcode
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _barcode = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _desc As String = Nothing
        Public Property desc As String
            Get
                Return _desc
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _desc = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _um As String = Nothing
        Public Property um As String
            Get
                Return _um
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _um = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _qta As Single = Nothing
        Public Property qta As Single
            Get
                Return _qta
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Single)
                _qta = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _id_testata As Integer = Nothing
        Public Property id_testata As Integer
            Get
                Return _id_testata
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _id_testata = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _tipo_frontalino As String = Nothing
        Public Property tipo_frontalino As String
            Get
                Return _tipo_frontalino
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _tipo_frontalino = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private _timestamp As Long = Nothing
        Public Property timestamp As Long
            Get
                Return _timestamp
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Long)
                _timestamp = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: Why is the question tagged [tag:c#]? What c# solutions you are welcome?

Comment: have you tried _adding setters_?

Comment: Which line gives you the error message?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i've updated the code with the setters i've tried and if i change the whole code with getters and setters i'm unable to set the object i just get Nothing instead

Comment: @DavidG i get errors everywhere here is a [screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/958c22841b6fbc3456967ff308ad7572.png)

Comment: Oh I see, well I think possibly VB.NET didn't have auto-properties back then, so you probably need to fall back to the old way of writing them.

Comment: By ".NET 2.0 Project", do you mean it has to comply with .NET *Standard* 2.0? Going back some 15 years to .NET *Framework* 2.0 seems an unlikely requirement.

Comment: @AndrewMorton it's .NET Framework 2.0 so yeah back to 15 years...

Comment: @NiceToMytyuk 1) Is the project set to use Option Strict On? 2) If instances of the class have their properties as `Nothing`, that suggests that whatever initiates the instances is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure VB.NET didn't have auto-properties back then, so you will need to change your code to use the classic properties with a backing field. For example:

```
' Backing field
Private _cod As String = "Empty"

' Classic property getter and setter
Property cod As String
    Get
        Return _cod
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _cod = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Tried to rewrite the whole class and damn it's working in Framework 4.7 when i send data (which before with empty getter and setter wasnt) but in Framework 2.0 it's still unable to get data in object..